Git Bash: Command Not Found Error - How to Resolve?
I'm currently experiencing an issue with Git Bash on my Windows machine. When I try to run any git command, I receive a command not found error.
Here are some details about my setup and what I've tried so far:

I have installed Git for Windows and can access Git Bash.
When I type git --version, it returns command not found.
I have tried adding the Git executable path to the system's PATH environment variable, but the issue persists.
Restarted my computer after making changes to the PATH variable.
Verified that the Git executable exists in the specified directory.

Here are my system details:

OS: Windows 10
Git version: [2.45.2.windows.1]

Could anyone help me understand what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it?
Thank you!

Is this specific to Git Bash or does the regular Windows cmd not know the git command either? Also, have you tried a clean re-install and made sure you had "Git from the command line and also from 3rd-party software" option checked during the install?

It work well in cmd. I have try re-install for several time already. It seem like git bash not known any command except basic command like pwd or cd.

does echo $PATH in the bash include /mingw64/bin somewhere near the start? That's where mine finds the git executable and it seems to be prepended to the Windows %PATH%

I don't find any related /mingw64/bin in my path. So what should I do next?

If you've already tried the usual (uninstalling and reinstalling Git, and rebooting Windows) you may need to prepend those paths manually in a ~/.bashrc with export PATH="/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH"

Thank you it's work well now. Can you tell me what is ~/.bashrc and what is it used for ?

short for "bash read command", it's a script that's executed every time you start your Bash. Normally though, if I'm reading this right, the path should be modified by C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile instead, I don't know what's wrong with your installation.

The path is right but in my ~/.bashrc file have  eval "$(fnm env)"  export="PATH TO fnm" I simply remove and save it then it work as normally Thank you dude
